# HTML select option in < >

Tags: html, select

Is there a way how to render option in the select tag if options wrapped by "< >"?

```
<select>
    <option>First</option>
    <option><Second></option>
    <option>Third</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kn59m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in HTML you need use `&lt;` to display `<` and similarly use `&gt` to display `>`

```
<select>
    <option>First</option>
    <option>&lt;Second&gt;</option>
    <option>Third</option>
</select>
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kn59m/1/)

here is full [list of such special characters](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).

Comment: What it my select is dynamic? User added words on some page, and I will render his words on the another page in the select like options.

Comment: If so, you will need to replace such characters when adding to select.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option>&lt;Second&gt;</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<option>&lt;Second&gt;</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters `<` and `>` using `&#60;` and `&#62;`:

```
<option>&#60;Second&#62;</option>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kn59m/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just use `<option>&lt;Second&gt;</option>`

See fiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/kn59m/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
   <option>First</option>
   <option>&lt; Second &gt;</option>
   <option>Third</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcferrans/Q637M/